# Laravel validation rule to create only one post per month

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Is it possible to create a validation in Laravel that will allow a user to only create one post per month?

Comment: You can add a field in database user named last_posted, when he make a post, just check if the date from now to last_posted is more than 1 month or not

Comment: place it to controller ??

Comment: you can make a policy and check the user last post date inside it

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Laravel you are using, and you omitted a lot of data about schema and so, but let me try to help here.

You can check how to  do custom validation https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#custom-validation-rules (the below solution would work for Laravel 5 as well)

```
Validator::extend('hasnt-posted-in-last-month', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return \App\Post::where('author_id', auth()->user()->id)
        ->where('created_at', '>=', now()->subMonth())
        ->count() === 0;
});
```

The code above has some premises:
1) You have a Post model in the app folder
2) You have withTimestamps() in your migration for the post table
3) Your user is always logged in when they reach this part of the code

Then you need to call this validation when you are calling your request (or use it inside your controller with the Validator::make)

Note: For a better UX for your users, you should let them know beforehand that they are not allowed to post, so they don't fill all the form to send a post and then get an error.